using npx remix vite:build unexpected token ? due to "??"
This may be similar to npx hardhat compile Unexpected token?
I'm using Node 20.12 and npm 10.5. I'm going through the Quick start for Remix as I start a new project learning React and Remix. When I get to the part for building with:
npx remix vite:build

it gives the following error:
ode_modules/@remix-run/dev/dist/cli/run.js:231
  flags.interactive = flags.interactive ?? require.main === module;
                                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

I've clear npm cache. Reinstalled Node and restarted the process with the Quick start but always the same error.

What does tsconfig.json look like?

There is no tsconfig.json because remix uses Vite for compile/build. So here is the vite.config.js:
import { vitePlugin as remix } from "@remix-run/dev";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [remix()],
});

Oddly enough, the error is coming from a .js file where '??' should be valid.

Can you create a simple repro? This should just work, so it looks like an issue with your setup.

Agreed, most likely an issue with my setup. I just followed the info on https://remix.run/docs/en/main/start/quickstart starting with the "mkdir my-remix-app" command and working my way down. Not sure what other items need configuring given the Node and npm versions listed above. BTW there is no indication on the Quick setup page on what versions of those are needed.

Ah, I see. I haven't gone through the quickstart. So I followed the steps up to running the build and it build successfully. Here's a screenshot. https://github.com/kiliman/remix-flat-routes/assets/47168/cf71057b-033b-484a-97af-3ff0f9f571fc

Have you just tried initializing a new project using create-remix? If you want JavaScript, you can run npx create-remix@latest --template remix-run/remix/templates/remix-javascript

As @Killman mentioned, it was a configuration issue. Apparently, I had a \node_modules folder in the project's parent directory that was ignored during npm installs, etc, but was used during the vite:build. Annoying, but true. I deleted that folder and everything seems to be fine.
An now, back to your regularly scheduled programming.
